# Using ChartbuilderDispatcher for loading external data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts

Using Chartbuilder 3.x and attempting to create an ability to load external objects to build charts. Currently a function exists that when you reload the page, a button appears that says "Reload Previous Data". It uses a localStorage object.

However the functions that load the data are anonymous.

Looking to create a button to load a specified version of a chart based on a local JSON object, not the localStorage object.

The chart uses this function but as I said it is anonymous at runtime so I cannot test via consolhttp://quartz.github.io/Chartbuilder/api-docs/#ChartbuilderDispatcher

The call currently is:
`ChartServerActions.receiveModel(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("model")));`

The application already does a great job of storing state, but Id like to be able to add functionality instead or replacing it.